# How to find all transformations whose kernels are $\operatorname{span}(\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^{\textrm{T}})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951777/find-a-linear-transformation-whose-kernel-is-the-line-spanned-by-1-1-2-in) with a similar problem, however, the answers don't touch on how to actually find the matrix beyond just eye-balling it (which is trivial for this example). So my question is: how do I algorithmically find all such transformations?

Moreover, the responses only had matrices that either had 2 or 3 rows. Do the standard matrices have to be $2 \times 3$ or $3 \times 3$, or can it be $3 \times n$, where $n \ge 1$?

For matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 3}$ and $\vec{v} = \operatorname{span}(\; \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \;)$, we can have:

\begin{equation*}
A = k\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \mathrm{or} \ \ \
A = k\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \mathrm{or} \ \ \
A = k\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1/2 \end{bmatrix} \\  \text{for all} \ k \in \mathbb{R}\ \text{such that} \ A\vec{v} = \vec{0}.
\end{equation*}

This shows that it seems to work for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 3}$? To continue, for $B \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}$, I'm assuming we basically do the same thing by simply placing all combinations of $A$ onto their own rows in $B$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232695/how-to-find-the-orthogonal-complement-of-a-subspace/1232747#1232747

Answer (score 1):

The ideas the following: when we want to find a linear transformation, all we need to know is which starting vector space to which target vector space we want the mapping to be made, *a basis for the starting vector space* and to know *how the linear transformation affects these basis vectors*. If we know these components, the *idea is to use the definition directly to make the linear transformation*.

Since your question seems to be an attempt to understand this idea, there are still things you need to specify (as the target vector space). *In the specific case* that you want to find a linear transformation $A:{\bf R}^3\to {\bf R}^2$ such that $\ker(A)={\rm span}\{(-1,1,2)\}$ so first we need *a basis* (not *the* basis) for ${\bf R}^3$ but since we have the kernel and we know that the kernel is always subspace of the starting vector space we can use this vector to add our basis of ${\bf R}^{3}$ call it $$\beta=\{(-1,1,2),v_2,v_3\}$$ and noticed that we have vectors $v_2,v_3$ in $\beta$ its raison to be is that in order to have a basis for ${\bf R}^3$ we need three vectors spanning and linearly independents. That is all that its exercise imposes as condition, so *we have some freedom to select these vectors* $v_2$ and $v_3$ for convenience we take the canonical ones and we have $$\beta=\{(-1,1,2),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$$
Well, we already have a base of ${\bf R}^3$ that also satisfies the condition that it imposes. Why? Well, by definition we know that $A(-1,1,2)=(0,0)$ (why?). However, for now we do not know $A(0,1,0)$ and $A(0,0,1)$ and since your problem doesn't add more restrictions, *we again have some freedom but now a bit conditioned*  since we can't even send these vectors to the kernel (why?), so we setting
$A(0,1,0)=(1,0)$ and $A(0,0,1)=(0,1)$.

Summarizing everything, then we have

- Linear transformation: $A:{\bf R}^3\to {\bf R}^2$.
- A basis: $\beta=\{(-1,1,2),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.
- Conditions: $A(-1,1,2)=(0,0), A(0,1,0)=(1,0)$ and $A(0,0,1)=(0,1)$.

Using all it, now we can use the definition of linear transformation to make the rule for $A$, finding $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ in
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\alpha_{1}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}+\alpha_2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\alpha_{3}\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
I will let you solve the linear system and find $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$.
Finally, the definition the linear transformation give

$$A\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\alpha_{1}A\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}+\alpha_2A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\alpha_3\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
I think you can conclude.

Now I think you can see that there is nothing special in ${\bf R}^2$ and that the same idea can be used with another target vector space as ${\bf R}^{n}, M_{m\times n}({\bf R}), P_{n}({\bf R})$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think if your matrix isn't square, it isn't a linear transformation, since it changes the dimension of the vector it's acting on.

To answer your other question, you need a square matrix to be a linear transformation, so construct a square matrix, say $$A := \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\ a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}.$$
Next, as you said, if $\vec{v}$ is the vector which spans the kernel, then the kernel itself is the set of all $k\vec{v}, k\in\mathbb{R}$. So set $A(k\vec{v}) = [0&0&0]^T$ and you'll get signs on all the $a_{ij}$s that should hopefully give you a hint of what your matrix $A$ should look like.