# Linear transformation - question

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is there a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{Ker}(T)$$

and there exists only one $v\in\Bbb R^3$ for which

$$T(v) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} \quad ?$$

It feels abstract to me and I'm struggling to find a concrete example to "test" stuff. I'd highly appreciate some help

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4632796/1027216 maybe it is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $w=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. Assume such a transformation $T$ exists, and let $v\in\mathbb{R^3}$ be the unique vector such that $T(v)=w$. Now, what is $T(v+w)$?

Comment: Thanks, it seems very obvious now. May I know what was your intuition when you solved it? I mean, are there some guidelines which I should follow?

Comment: @X4J The intuition is simple. I believe you know that if only the zero vector is mapped to $0$ (i.e if the kernel is trivial) then $T$ must be injective. However, there is nothing special about the zero vector. If for some $w$ there exists a unique $v$ such that $T(v)=w$ then it means $T$ must be injective. (the reason is just as described in the answer: if you add an element from $Ker(T)$ to $v$, you again get an element mapped to $w$) So in your case, if $T$ would exist then it would have to be injective. But it clearly isn't, because the vector $w$ belongs to the kernel by assumption.

Comment: Thank you mate. So basically, according to that I can deduce that if A is a nxn matrices which the equation Ax=b for some vector b has a unique solution then A is invertible?

Comment: @X4J Yes, this is true. If $A$ is not invertible then for every vector $b$, either there is no solution or there is more than one solution.